# How can I create more advanced layouts in Gutenberg block editor?

Tags: block-editor, screen-layout

I'm looking to create a layout like the below, which is enabled by the [Stackable](https://wpstackable.com/blog/introducing-the-advanced-columns-and-grid-block/) plugin.

I know exactly how I would do this if I was using [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/), but because I want this to be easily drag-and-droppable by the client I'm making the site for (instead of asking them to write code), I'm looking for the best way to do it using Blocks.

I don't especially think that signing up to Stackable and paying a yearly subscription, for one small feature, is the best solution, so would appreciate if anyone has any suggestions on how to do this, or if there is a plugin available with this capability.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Is your question how to set up responsive column layouts? You could create a custom theme, or a child theme, that makes the Core Columns block responsive if that's all you're needing to do. Core Blocks can already create most layouts imaginable, especially when paired with a well-coded theme. You may also want to look into Block Patterns, which allow you to create template block groups that can be added all at once and then filled out.

Comment: I would tackle this by building a custom ACF block for Gutenberg, not sure if you have ACF, but the net result would be build your own block regardless.

Atomic Blocks is free and does have a few more options you could explore.